# JMP, JL, JG in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

So the program is given two number a and b and print out all the numbers between them.
Eg. a = 2; b = 5 ---> output: 2 3 4 5
My code is like this:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.data

.code
start:
    call main
    exit
    main proc
        local a:dword
        local b:dword
        mov a, sval(input("a: "))
        mov b, sval(input("b: "))
        mov eax, a
        mov ebx, b
        jmp LAP
    LAP:
        cmp ebx, eax
        jl TASK
        jg KETTHUC
            
    TASK:
        print str$(eax)
        inc eax
        jmp LAP
    KETTHUC:
        ret
    main endp
end start
```

It does not output anything!! Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"It does not output anything"_? Does it show the prompts for a and b but not the resulting sequence? Or are the prompts not shown either?

Comment: `cmp ebx, eax` seems reversed - `jl TASK` seems redundant, as does the first `jmp LAP`.

Comment: I got that fixed..Thank you all!!